# Android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

Im trying to get a simple trinangle showing in a Android OpenGL ES 2.0 example. But nothing appears and i just dont get why :), i get no errors or anything, just a blue screen (that is my clear color). Maybe theres something wrong with the projection matrix placing my model outside?

```
package dk.madslee.modelviewer;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

// http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/GLES20TriangleRenderer.html

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Resources resources = getResources();
        GLSurfaceView surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        surfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2); // enable OpenGL 2.0

        Log.e("opengl", Boolean.toString(detectOpenGLES20()));

        surfaceView.setRenderer(new GLSurfaceView.Renderer()
        {   
            public static final int FLOAT_BYTE_LENGTH = 4;

            private int mProgram;
            private int mVertexPositionAttributeLocation;
            private int mMVMatrixUniformLocation;
            private int mPMatrixUniformLocation;

            private float[] mMVMatrix = new float[16];
            private float[] mPMatrix = new float[16];

            private float[] mVertices = {
                1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            };
            private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
            {
                mVertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVertices.length * FLOAT_BYTE_LENGTH).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
                mVertexBuffer.put(mVertices);
                mVertexBuffer.position(0);

                mProgram = createProgram();
                mVertexPositionAttributeLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aVertexPosition");
                mMVMatrixUniformLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVMatrix");
                mPMatrixUniformLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "mPMatrix");
                checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

                Matrix.setLookAtM(mMVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
            {
                GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

                Matrix.frustumM(mPMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 7); // [UPDATED but didnt solve the problem]
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
            {
                GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                GLES20.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

                GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
                checkGlError("glUseProgram");

                mVertexBuffer.position(0);

                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mVertexPositionAttributeLocation, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * FLOAT_BYTE_LENGTH, mVertexBuffer);
                checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mVertexPositionAttributeLocation);
                checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixUniformLocation, 1, false, mMVMatrix, 0);
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mPMatrixUniformLocation, 1, false, mPMatrix, 0);
                checkGlError("glUniform4fv");

                GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
                checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
            }

            private int createProgram()
            {
                int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

                int vertexShader = getShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, R.string.vertex_shader);
                int fragmentShader = getShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, R.string.fragment_shader);

                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
                GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
                GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

                return program;
            }

            private int getShader(int type, int source) 
            {
                int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
                String shaderSource = resources.getString(source);
                GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
                GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

                int[] compiled = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
                if (compiled[0] == 0) 
                {
                    Log.e("opengl", "Could not compile shader");
                    Log.e("opengl", GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                    Log.e("opengl", shaderSource);
                }

                return shader;
            }

            private void checkGlError(String op) {
                int error;
                while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
                    Log.e("opengl", op + ": glError " + error);
                    throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
                }
            }
        });

        setContentView(surfaceView);   
    }

    private boolean detectOpenGLES20() {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConfigurationInfo info = am.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        return (info.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000);
    }
}
```

My shaders looks like this

Vertex

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        }
```

Fragment

```
precision highp float; 
        void main() {
          gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to disable back face culling (by `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`), as at the moment you're looking at the back of your geometry, or try using 5 instead of -5 in the look at. It should actually be disabled by default, but I'm not sure about that.

Otherwise it could be your projection matrix. Keep in mind, that the parameters to frustum are in generic (3d world) units and not necessarily in pixels, so you should not take the same values you put into `glViewport` if you don't want the world units to represent pixels. So at the moment your image plane is (2*width)x(2*height) and your triangle occupies only a pixel (actually even less, due to perspective distortion). Try something like `Matrix.frustumM(mPMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 7)` or use an equivalent to `gluPerspective` where you can just put in the desired viewing angle and the window's aspect ratio, which is much more natural than the direct frustum parameters.

**EDIT:** Just found the problem. In `glGetUniformLocation` you wrote `mPMatrix` instead of `uPMatrix`, so you never got a valid uniform location for the projection matrix. Strange that GL didn't throw an error on this.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your suggestions, i tried them all but nothing appeared to fix the problem, you are suggesting that i use the gluPerspective but isnt that a OpenGL 1.x feature and not supported by OpenGL 2.0?

Comment: There is one spot in the code im a bit unsure if correct and thats the call where i set the GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mVertexPositionAttributeLocation, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * FLOAT_BYTE_LENGTH, mVertexBuffer); maybe im doing something wrong there? or maybe i should try using Buffers instead?

Comment: @madsleejensen I didn't mean to use deprecated functionaltity. I just thought that there is a similar method for this Matrix class, as there seem to be methods for the other deprecated things like glOrtho and glFrustum. You `glVertexAttribPointer` call seems ok, you could set the stride to 0 if the values are tightly packed (like in your case), but it should also work like it is.

Comment: Hi Christian, seems like you were spot on, in that it had something to do with the matrix's. I got it working by changing the way i multiply the different matrix's http://pastebin.com/NH5nbPYj now i use Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0); and just send in a single matrix which i multiply in my vertex shader with the vertex position. Is there a logic explanation why it works with this approach and not the other.

Comment: @madsleejensen Sounds really strange if that is the only thing you changed. Oh, I got it, will update my answer.

Comment: Im afraid it is, i created a new example where you can see it http://pastebin.com/0GNL5gCu

Comment: @madsleejensen Does it work now with `"mPMatrix"` changed to `"uPMatrix"`?

Comment: Christian im not sure what you mean, the uniforms seems to be bound correctly, i dont have a variable called "mPMatrix" anywhere?

Comment: @madsleejensen That's what I meant in my updated answer. You accidentally worte `"mPMatrix"` in `glGetUniformLocation` (at least in the question code) so never got a valid uniform location for the projection matrix. That was the error I think, along with the wrong frustum arguments.

Comment: Hi Christian you were absolutely right! Thank you very much! damn typo can really cause alot of frustration! Thanks again!